# Responsive webpage layout breaks on certain mobile devices - Need to ensure cross-device compatibility

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having **difficulty in achieving responsiveness for my homepage** on certain mobile devices, despite implementing CSS media queries. While the site appears to work well on some mobiles, on others, elements overlap, text gets cut off, buttons are distorted, and the overall layout becomes unusable. I require assistance to identify the root causes and a potential solution that ensures cross-device compatibility for my webpage.

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='eng'>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>FITIFY || Fitness Tracker</title>
  <!--Bootstrap Scripts(CSS)-->
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <!--Awesome Fonts-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fd6cc398e6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Google Fonts-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@800&family=Roboto+Mono&family=Instrument+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--CSS Styling-->
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: gold;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bolder;
    }
    
    h2,
    h3 {
      color: white;
      margin: 6%;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Instrument Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    h5 {
      background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      background-clip: text;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      margin: 3%;
    }
    
    .nav-brand {
      margin: 1%;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .btn {
      background-color: #19376D;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: green;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
      width: 40%;
      margin-right: 0%;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .main-box {
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3d97ce 0%, #12debb 100%);
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      border-bottom: solid black 3px;
      margin-top: 7%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .main-text-box {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #main-para {
      color: white;
      text-align: left;
      margin: 2% 2% 2% 10%;
      font-size: 22px;
      visibility: hidden;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .main-image-box {
      float: right;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #main-img {
      width: 80%;
      height: 80%;
      margin: 5%;
      border: white solid 3px;
    }
    
    #to-features {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      border: solid 2.5px;
      border-image-slice: 1;
      border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
      width: 10%;
      height: 10%;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0% 40% 0% 20%;
      bottom: 10%;
      font-family: 'Instrument Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .feature-box {
      background: linear-gradient(to top right, #3d97ce 0%, #12debb 100%);
      background-size: cover;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .card {
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
      width: 21%;
      height: 250px;
      margin: 14% 2% 10% 2%;
    }
    
    .row {
      margin-right: 0%;
    }
    
    .cards-btn {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      border: solid 3px;
      border-image-slice: 1;
      border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
      padding: 2%;
      margin: 50px 10% 2% 20%;
      font-family: 'Instrument Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .cards-btn:hover {
      color: green;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 650px) {
      /*targets mobile devices */
      h1 {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
      }
      .nav-brand {
        width: 10%;
      }
      a {
        margin: 0.5%;
        font-size: 0.7rem;
      }
      .nav-links {
        width: 75%;
      }
      .btn {
        font-size: 45%;
      }
      .main-box {
        margin-top: 12%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .main-text-box {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #main-para {
        font-size: 1.3rem;
      }
      .main-image-box {
        display: none;
      }
      #to-features {
        width: 40%;
        height: 6%;
        padding: 1%;
        margin: 10% 20% 0% 30%;
        bottom: 17%;
      }
      .card {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 15% 20% 5% 20%;
      }
      #goal-btn {
        padding: 1%;
        margin-left: 10%;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 651px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 3rem;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 4rem;
      }
      a {
        margin: 2%;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
      }
      .nav-links {
        margin: 0%;
        width: 75%;
      }
      .btn {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        margin-right: 1%;
      }
      .main-box {
        margin-top: 8%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .main-text-box {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #main-para {
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      .main-image-box {
        display: none;
      }
      #to-features {
        width: 30%;
        height: 9%;
        padding: 1%;
        margin: 8% 20% 0% 35%;
      }
      .card {
        width: 30%;
        margin: 15% 10% 5% 35%;
      }
      #goal-btn {
        margin-left: 10%;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 1800px) and (max-width: 2600px) {
      /* 4k */
      h1 {
        font-size: 6rem;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 5rem;
        font-weight: bolder;
      }
      a {
        margin: 5%;
        font-size: 3rem;
      }
      .nav-links {
        margin: 0%;
        width: 55%;
      }
      .btn {
        font-size: 3rem;
        margin-right: 10%;
      }
      .main-box {
        margin-top: 6%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      #main-para {
        font-size: 60px;
      }
      #to-features {
        width: 20%;
        height: 9%;
        padding: 1%;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 10% 0% 0% 15%;
      }
      .card {
        width: 20%;
        margin: 15% 10% 5% 35%;
      }
      .card {
        width: 20%;
        height: 250px;
        margin: 15% 3% 10% 2%;
      }
      #goal-btn {
        margin-left: 10%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark fixed-top" data-bs-theme="dark">
      <div class="nav-brand">
        <h1>FITIFY</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <a href="./index.html">HOME</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      FEATURES
                    </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu gap-1 p-2 rounded-3 mx-0 shadow w-220px" data-bs-theme="light">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-2" href="./bmi.html">BMI CALCULATOR</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-2" href="./calories.html">TRACK CALORIES</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-2" href="./goal.html">KNOW YOUR GOAL</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-2" href="./basic_redirect.html">STORE YOUR DETAILS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="./about.html">ABOUT US</a>
        <a href="./contacts.html">CONTACT US</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="main-box">
      <div class="main-text-box">
        <h2>Transform yourself today.</h2>
        <p id="main-para">"Welcome to Fitify, your ultimate fitness companion! We are dedicated to helping you on your fitness journey by providing powerful tools to track your progress. With our user-friendly interface achieving your health and fitness goals has never
          been easier. Join our community today and take the first step towards a healthier, fitter you!"</p>
        <button id="to-features">GET FIT</button>
      </div>
      <div class="main-image-box"> //This div will be hidden on mobile devices
        <img src="./nutri.webp" id="main-img" alt="Display Image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dumbbell"></i>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">CALCULATE YOUR BMI</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Calculate your Body Mass Index (BMI) to know your health status right away.</p><br>
            <a href="./bmi.html" class="cards-btn">CALCULATE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-utensils"></i>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">TRACK YOUR CALORIES</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Track your calories for the day and know how much you consumed today.</p>
            <a href="./calories.html" class="cards-btn">TRACK NOW</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-person-dress"></i>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">YOUR IDEAL WEIGHT</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Calculate your ideal weight by entering your measurements.</p><br>
            <a href="./goal.html" class="cards-btn" id="goal-btn">KNOW YOUR GOAL</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-info"></i>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">STORE YOUR BASIC DETAILS</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Keep a log of your basic information in our secure database.</p>
            <a href="./basic_redirect.html" class="cards-btn">STORE DETAILS</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-heAjqF+bCxXpCWLa6Zhcp4fu20XoNIA98ecBC1YkdXhszjoejr5y9Q77hIrv8R9i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    const button = document.getElementById('to-features');
    window.onload = function() {
      var para = document.getElementById("main-para");
      var para_text = para.innerHTML;
      var speed = 15;
      var i = 0;
      para.innerHTML = "";

      function typeWriter_para() {
        if (i < para_text.length) {
          para.innerHTML += para_text.charAt(i);
          i++;
          setTimeout(typeWriter_para, speed);
        }
      }
      setTimeout(typeWriter_para, 100); // Delay before starting the paragraph animation
      para.style.visibility = "visible"; // Make the paragraph visible
    };
    const feature_box = document.querySelector('.feature-box');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      feature_box.scrollIntoView();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your responsiveness issues by using media queries and aspect ratios. See the syntax below. As per the aspect ratio, the responsiveness of your web app will be covered by using the format below.

```
 @media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/3) and (orientation: portrait) {}
 @media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/3) and (orientation: landscape) {}
 @media (min-aspect-ratio: 9/16) and (orientation: landscape) {}
 @media (min-aspect-ratio: 9/16) and (orientation: portrait) {}
```